# me/onenote/pages Returns Empty Array

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

We are trying to list pages in OneNote using MS Graph and failing both on `/me` and other locations.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/pages
```

Calling this via `WebRequest` or Graph Explorer results in an empty array. The `/notebooks` and `/sections` work perfectly fine but we need to get into the actual page contents and can't seem to get any information out of the page layer regardless of how it is called.

Comment: Which scopes have you selected?

Comment: Could you elaborate as to what scopes I should have selected?

Comment: I'm asking which scopes you requested when you authorized the user. These are passed as part of `/authorization` URL.

Comment: It felt to me that the scopes during the authorization are used when you pass the url to the OneNote API itself (different url). I must have missed the mentions of using scopes when calling the graph one and it didn't seem like I needed any when using the Graph Explorer ? Looking at it now it seems that providing none results in default ?

Comment: Graph Explorer has a configuration screen for scopes.

Comment: Do you get the same results regardless of the user? Also, are you able to get a `pages` collection is your specify a `section` (`/sections/{id}/pages`)?

Comment: We tried a SharePoint hosted OneNote and the personal one. I personally assumed the easiest to get should be the /me one so was trying that route. I logged in with a GA account to elevate the permissions (which apparently i should be calling scopes) and allow the app full access / allow for all scopes but... no avail. Regardless if I call pages through `sections/{id}/pages` or `/me/onenote/pages` it wields empty value array – Jakub Lizińczyk 11 mins ago

Comment: If /notebooks and /sections work fine, then the scopes are properly set. Can you confirm that you have pages in the notebooks? Also, can you show us what the response preview looks like from Graph Explorer?

Comment: Yes there are pages in the nooteboks/sections created specifically for the purpose of reaching them with Graph.
The responses look like this:

`{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('guid')/onenote/pages",
    "value": []
}`

Comment: Would you mind sharing the client-request-id header value from the response? Also let us know the date time when you made the request. Thanks!

Comment: client-request-id: 05104279-0e19-4195-927e-959567503c76

The request was made on 4/5/2018 (today) at 9:55 AM CET (GMT +1)

Comment: It does look like there are no pages under your 4 sections. Can you check please? Thanks much!

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding the concept of pages - but I just logged onto that environment and I have 3 sections and one page.

Comment: I know it's been forever but I am encountering this exact same issue, pages returns empty while notebooks and sessions work perfectly! Did you end up resolving this?